# pass by reference in device function CUDA

Tags: cuda, parameter-passing

I want to pass by reference in CUDA and pass the function in mex file Matlab, I called add_func which return multi-variables, and I pass this by pointer, but there has the problem when executing the code. Please take a look at my code and give me some advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "gpu/mxGPUArray.h"

typedef void(*op_func_t) (double, double, double*, double*);
typedef void(*my_func_t) (double, double, double, double, void (*func)(double, double, double *, double *));

__device__ void add_func(double x, double y, double *z, double *k)

{
    *z= x + y;
    *k= x + y;
}
__device__ void mul_func(double x, double y, double *z, double *k)

{   
    *z= x * y;
    *k= x * y;

}
__device__ void my_func(double x, double y, double z, double k, void (*func)(double, double, double *, double *))
{
    (*func)(x, y, &z, &k);
}


// Static pointers to device functions

__device__ op_func_t p_add_func = add_func;

__device__ op_func_t p_mul_func = mul_func;

__device__ my_func_t p_my_func = my_func;


__global__ void kernel(double const * const x, double const * const y,double * const u,double * const v, int const N, op_func_t op, op_func_t op1, my_func_t op2)

{
    int const i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (i<5)
        {
            (*op2)(x[i], y[i], u[i], v[i], op1);
        }
        else   
        {
            v[i]=10;
            u[i]=8;
        }
    __syncthreads();// wait for each thread to copy its elemenet
}

//host code

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

    /* Declare all variables.*/
    mxGPUArray const *A;
    mxGPUArray const *C;
    mxGPUArray *B;
    mxGPUArray *D;
    double const *d_A;
    double const *d_C;
    double *d_B;
    double *d_D;
    int N;

    /* Choose a reasonably sized number of threads for the block. */
    int const threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid;

    /* Initialize the MathWorks GPU API. */
    mxInitGPU();

    A = mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[0]);
    C = mxGPUCreateFromMxArray(prhs[1]);

    /*
     * Now that we have verified the data type, extract a pointer to the input
     * data on the device.
     */
    d_A = (double const *)(mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(A));
    d_C = (double const *)(mxGPUGetDataReadOnly(C));

    /* Create a GPUArray to hold the result and get its underlying pointer. */
    B = mxGPUCreateGPUArray(mxGPUGetNumberOfDimensions(A),
                            mxGPUGetDimensions(A),
                            mxGPUGetClassID(A),
                            mxGPUGetComplexity(A),
                            MX_GPU_DO_NOT_INITIALIZE);
    D = mxGPUCreateGPUArray(mxGPUGetNumberOfDimensions(A),
                            mxGPUGetDimensions(A),
                            mxGPUGetClassID(A),
                            mxGPUGetComplexity(A),
                            MX_GPU_DO_NOT_INITIALIZE);
    d_B = (double *)(mxGPUGetData(B));
    d_D = (double *)(mxGPUGetData(D));

    /*
     * Call the kernel using the CUDA runtime API. We are using a 1-d grid here,
     * and it would be possible for the number of elements to be too large for
     * the grid. For this example we are not guarding against this possibility.
     */
    N = (int)(mxGPUGetNumberOfElements(A));
    blocksPerGrid = (N + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    op_func_t h_add_func;

    op_func_t h_mul_func;

    my_func_t h_my_func;


    // Copy device function pointer to host side
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_mul_func, p_mul_func, sizeof(op_func_t));

    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_add_func, p_add_func, sizeof(op_func_t));

    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_my_func, p_my_func, sizeof(my_func_t));

    op_func_t d_myfunc = h_mul_func;
    op_func_t d_myfunc1 = h_add_func;
    my_func_t d_myfunc2 = h_my_func; 

    kernel <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_C, d_D ,d_B, N, d_myfunc, d_myfunc1, d_myfunc2);

    /* Wrap the result up as a MATLAB gpuArray for return. */
    plhs[0] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(B);
    plhs[1] = mxGPUCreateMxArrayOnGPU(D);
    /*
     * The mxGPUArray pointers are host-side structures that refer to device
     * data. These must be destroyed before leaving the MEX function.
     */
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(A);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(B);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(C);
    mxGPUDestroyGPUArray(D);

    return;

}
```

here is my results:

```
[a,b]=return_values(gpuArray(ones(10)),gpuArray(rand(10)))
```

a =

```
 0    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
 0    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
 0    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
 0    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
 0    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

b =

```
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
```

Some initialization code:

```
// Static pointers to device functions

    __device__ op_func_t p_add_func = add_func;

    __device__ op_func_t p_mul_func = mul_func;

    __device__ my_func_t p_my_func = my_func;

        op_func_t h_add_func;

        op_func_t h_mul_func;

        my_func_t h_my_func;


        // Copy device function pointer to host side
        cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_mul_func, p_mul_func, sizeof(op_func_t));

        cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_add_func, p_add_func, sizeof(op_func_t));

        cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_my_func, p_my_func, sizeof(my_func_t));

        op_func_t d_myfunc = h_mul_func;
        op_func_t d_myfunc1 = h_add_func;
        my_func_t d_myfunc2 = h_my_func;
```

Comment: What is the problem? It's not clear what you were expecting to get as a result.

Comment: What are `op_func_t ` and `my_func_t ` ?

Comment: Where are you initializing all the kernel arguments?

Comment: thank you. I initializing in host code. but handled all pointer in device code

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input data?

Comment: I use mexfile in Matlab and generate function call return_values(). 
Here is matlab function I use:  [a,b]=return_values(gpuArray(ones(10)),gpuArray(rand(10))). Another question that how can I add provided as an edit to the question. I want to add all my code for the question.

Comment: You may click the edit link right beneath your question. If you could please provide which would be the numerical values for ones(10) and rand(10) that would help for people that is not using matlab.

Comment: thank you.  ones(10) and rand(10) is function create a matrix 10x10 that all values are 1 or random values, respectively. so all 5 first values in the results should be 1+ rand() according to my code, but I get all zero values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems here. This:

```
__device__ void my_func(double x, double y, double z, double k, void (*func)(double, double, double *, double *))
{
    (*func)(x, y, &z, &k);
}
```

is broken. The modified values of z and k will never be return to the caller because of pass-by-value. You can fix this by using references (CUDA is C++ based, and references are supported in __device__ functions):

```
typedef void(*op_func_t) (double, double, double&, double&);
typedef void(*my_func_t) (double, double, double&, double&, void (*func)(double, double, double &, double &));

__device__ void add_func(double x, double y, double& z, double& k)

{
    z= x + y;
    k= x + y;
}
__device__ void mul_func(double x, double y, double& z, double& k)

{   
    z= x * y;
    k= x * y;

}
__device__ void my_func(double x, double y, double& z, double& k, void (*func)(double, double, double&, double&))
{
    (*func)(x, y, z, k);
}
```

The second problem is a lack of bounds checking within the kernel, which will lead to out-of-bounds memory access when `N` is not an exact multiple of `threadsPerBlock`.

When I fix both these things in your code like this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef void(*op_func_t) (double, double, double&, double&);
typedef void(*my_func_t) (double, double, double&, double&, void (*func)(double, double, double &, double &));

__device__ void add_func(double x, double y, double& z, double& k)

{
    z= x + y;
    k= x + y;
}
__device__ void mul_func(double x, double y, double& z, double& k)

{   
    z= x * y;
    k= x * y;

}
__device__ void my_func(double x, double y, double& z, double& k, void (*func)(double, double, double&, double&))
{
    (*func)(x, y, z, k);
}


// Static pointers to device functions

__device__ op_func_t p_add_func = add_func;
__device__ op_func_t p_mul_func = mul_func;
__device__ my_func_t p_my_func = my_func;

__global__ void kernel(double const * const x, double const * const y,double * const u,double * const v, int const N, op_func_t op, op_func_t op1, my_func_t op2)
{
    int const i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

        if (i<5) {
            (*op2)(x[i], y[i], u[i], v[i], op1);
        } else if (i<N)   {
            v[i]=10;
            u[i]=8;
        }
}

//host code

int main()
{
    const size_t n = 5;
    const size_t N = n * n;

    /* Declare all variables.*/
    thrust::device_vector<double> A(N, 1.0);
    thrust::device_vector<double> C(N, 1.0);
    thrust::device_vector<double> B(N);
    thrust::device_vector<double> D(N);
    double *d_A = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(A.data()); 
    double *d_C = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(C.data());  
    double *d_B = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(B.data()); 
    double *d_D = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(D.data()); 


    /* Choose a reasonably sized number of threads for the block. */
    int const threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid;

    blocksPerGrid = (N + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    op_func_t h_add_func;
    op_func_t h_mul_func;
    my_func_t h_my_func;

    // Copy device function pointer to host side
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_mul_func, p_mul_func, sizeof(op_func_t));
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_add_func, p_add_func, sizeof(op_func_t));
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_my_func, p_my_func, sizeof(my_func_t));

    op_func_t d_myfunc = h_mul_func;
    op_func_t d_myfunc1 = h_add_func;
    my_func_t d_myfunc2 = h_my_func; 

    kernel <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_C, d_D ,d_B, N, d_myfunc, d_myfunc1, d_myfunc2);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(const auto bval: B)
        std::cout << bval << std::endl;

    for(const auto dval: D)
        std::cout << dval << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the CUDA part of your code works correctly, as far as I can tell:

```
$ nvcc -o mexhead -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 mexhead.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./mexhead 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
2
2
2
2
2
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
2
2
2
2
2
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```